# What is up with this golden poop?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I found this fancy golden poop. What makes it different from regular poops?

[image]

Comment: Same as the golden poop in the first one. There is also a rainbow colored poop. Haven't found what that does, except destroying it pops up a rainbow for a second.

Comment: @Arperum The rainbow poop restores health. I've popped it twice now and it restored me to full health both times. It may have other effects as well though, since the rainbow baby and $3 dollar bill (rainbow tears) are both randomized tear types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will drop a significant amount of coins when broken, and has a chance to drop the golden coin trinket, like [Darrell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/91481/darrell) commented.

Comment: Rarely it will drop the golden coin trinket which increases the amount of coins you get

Comment: @3ventic do you mind editing your answer to reflect the coin trinket before I accept? I feel like that's good to know :3

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't necessarily drop anything. I just broke one that dropped nothing at all, but still gave the rainbow on the screen and the sound effect.